# Can I measure cold boot time using logs?

Tags: gnome, grub, time

I want to measure the time it takes from loading grub until GNOME starts. Can I do this using existing logs?

What alternatives do I have to measure the time it takes from grub until GNOME loads?

Comment: Haven't looked at it much myself, but you have e.g. http://www.bootchart.org/ , [on arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bootchart).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It pretty much depends on the Operating System you are using.

If your OS still uses the old initscripts an rc.d system, then use something like [Bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/index.html) to measure the Booting time. Bootchart will require you to temporarily modify your kernel parameters to make it the first thing being executed.
Add the following to your kernel line at the GRUB Menu:

> init=/sbin/bootchartd

So your Kernel line looks something like this:

> kernel /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/vg/root
>   video=uvesafb:mtrr:3,ywrap,1680x1050-24@60 console=tty1
>   init=/sbin/bootchartd

In case you use the newer systemd init system (Fedora, Arch Linux, etc) then, the process is even simpler. Systemd comes with a boot process analyzer that you can simply run by calling:

> $ systemd-analyze

To get more information about what is taking up maximum time, use the blame command.

> $ systemd-analyze blame

For a Bootchart like SVG representation, use the plot command.

> $ systemd-analyze plot > ~/bootup.svg

Comment: I have systemd init system but no systemd-analyze

Comment: What distro are you using? It is possible that your distro strips systemd-core from other utilities in separate packages.

Comment: systemd-analyze wasn't default , but I added it afterwards with zypper and it works. But I think bootchart is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would make a first attempt.

Check out the scripts in `/etc/grub.d`.

See if it is possible to echo the time to a file. Or what about displaying it on the screen?

Then, do the same in `/etc/init.d/gdm3`. Or, put a script to do this, to be executed right before the `gdm3` script, in `/etc/rc2.d` (that is, if you don't want to muck around with the original desktop manager initialization file).